# How would you show $\cos^2(x)\sin^3(x)=\frac{1}{16}(2\sin(x)+\sin(3x)-\sin(5x))$

Tags: trigonometry

> $$\cos^2(x)\sin^3(x)=\frac{1}{16}(2\sin(x)+\sin(3x)-\sin(5x))$$

This is my try

$$\cos(x)\sin(x) \cos(x) \sin^2(x))$$

$$\frac{1}{4}\sin(2x)\cos(x)\sin^2(x)$$

$$\frac 1 4\sin(2x) \frac 1 4\sin(2x)\sin(x)$$

$$\frac 1 {16} * \frac 1 2(\sin(2x+2x)+\sin(0x)) \sin(x)$$

But I am kind of stuck.

Comment: Title says $ain^3(x)$, do you mean $sin^3(x)$ ?

Comment: oh yes sorry sorry

Comment: I just edited your question so it was easier to read for me and because it was missing an open parenthesis. Can you please check that I did not misinterpret what you meant with my edits? Thanks!

Comment: It seems ok to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F=\cos^2x\sin^3x=\frac{\sin x}4(2\sin x\cos x)^2$$ as $\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$

$$F=\dfrac{\sin x(1-\cos4x)}8$$ as $\cos2A=1-2\sin^2A$

Now,
$$\sin x(1-\cos4x)=\dfrac{2\sin x-2\sin x\cos4x}2=\dfrac{2\sin x-(\sin5x-\sin3x)}2$$

using [Werner Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html)

Answer (score 2):

$\cos^2(x)\sin^3(x)$ is a $2\pi$-periodic odd function with a finite expansion as a Fourier sine series.

By exploiting De Moivre's identities
$$ \sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i},\qquad \cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$
and the binomial theorem, the claim follows by straightforward algebra: it is essentially the same as computing the coefficients of the polynomial $(t^2+1)^2 (t^2-1)^3$.

Answer (score 2):

Write $\sin 3x- \sin 5x = -2\cos 4x\sin x$ so that the R.H.S. is $\dfrac{\sin x}{8} (1- \cos 4x) = \dfrac{\sin x}{4}(\sin^2 2x)$ and use $\sin 2x=2 \sin x \cos x$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard formulae: $\sin5x=5c^4s-10c^2x^3+s^5,\sin3x=3c^2s-s^3$, where $c=\cos x,s=\sin x$. s

So putting $c^2=1-s^2$ we have: $$2\sin x+\sin3x-\sin5x=2s+3(1-s^2)s-s^3-5(1-s^2)^2s+10(1-s^2)s^3-s^5$$ $$=16s^3-16s^5=16s^3c^2$$